# Add EditText and Spinner when button is clicked programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, addition

So I have a class that adds text fields and spinner dynamically when a button is pressed. The problem is the added text fields and buttons are not properly aligned. It's on top of each other but I want it to put beside each other. I set the orientation to "horizontal" but it doesnt work. Also the item list doesn't show up to the added spinner. Can someone help me? I'm new to android development. Thank you. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AddField extends Activity {

private LinearLayout mLayout, mLayout2;
private EditText qty, price ;
private Button mButton;
private Spinner mspinner;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_field);

    final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Male");
    list.add("Female");


 final String[] str={"Male","Female"};

    mspinner = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.itemSpin);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mspinner.setAdapter(adp1);



    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);





    qty = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.inputQty);

    price = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());





}

private OnClickListener onClick() {
return new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     mLayout2.addView(createNewSpin(mspinner.getContext().toString()));
    mLayout2.addView(createNewQty(qty.getText().toString()));
    mLayout2.addView(createNewPrice(price.getText().toString()));

}
};
}

private Spinner createNewSpin(String text) {


final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

final  Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
spinner.setLayoutParams(lparams);

return spinner;
}

private EditText createNewQty(String text) {


    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final  EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    editText.setHint("Quantity");
    return editText;
}


private EditText createNewPrice(String text) {
final LayoutParams paramss = new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

final  EditText editText2 = new EditText(this);
editText2.setLayoutParams(paramss);
editText2.setHint("Price");
return editText2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your import section? I suppose you should create `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` objects and pass `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` to constructor before instantiating your views.

**UPD.**
Remove `import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams` and just use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` class because you add your views programmatically on `LinearLayout`. After this try to set layout orientation to horizontal.
Also, when you create your spinner in `createNewSpin` method you should set adapter to it. The better way is to make a private field `mSpinnerAdapter` in activity class and instantiate it once when `onCreate`. Then every new `createnewSpin` call just set this adapter: `spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);` and you'll get list in each spinner you've created